# Binding command from SplitButton DropDownContent not working

Tags: .net, wpf, binding, mvvm

I have a `SplitButton` in my `usercontrol`, the `usercontrol`'s datacontext is a `view` which defines command I want the `splitbutton` binding to.

As my brief xaml code showing below, the first binding works, but the second (`button` in the `DropDownContent`) doesn't with the output:

> Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource
>   FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.UserControl....

or (if I replace binding expression using `ElementName` instead of `ReleativeSource`)

> Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=uc'...

```
<UserControl x:Name="uc"
             xmlns:extToolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit/extended"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             >
      <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList, IsAsync=True}">
          <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <extToolkit:SplitButton Command="{Binding 
                                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, 
                                                  Path=DataContext.OpenCommand, 
                                                  Mode=OneWay}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                      Content="{Binding ID}">
                <extToolkit:SplitButton.DropDownContent>
                  <Button  Command="{Binding 
                                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, 
                                         Path=DataContext.OpenCommand, 
                                         Mode=OneWay}"
                           CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                           Content="{Binding ID}"/>
                </extToolkit:SplitButton.DropDownContent>
              </extToolkit:SplitButton>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
      </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I found out

> the `DropDownContent` and it content in different visual tree
>   than the one that holds the `SplitButton`. This way the Binding to
>   RelativeSource cannot work, it does't find the desired relative source
>   since the they are in different visual trees.

[REF](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/buttons/radsplitbutton-with-contextmenu-in-dropdowncontent-binding-not-working.aspx#1934296) (although it's for another control, but I think they are based on the same thing)

So I have to add my VM as a property in the item object, and binding vm's command from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reference to your command as `Command="{x:Static someNamespace:SomeClass.OpenCommand}"`.